# jquery.html() returning undefined when jquery and bootstrap are working together

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

below is sample html + bootstrap code. When in javascript i write $("tbody").html(); its displaying "undefined". Please let me know what is the issue. Will jquery and bootstrap work together??

```
<div class="container">
    <h1>Your Shopping Cart</h1>
    <form id="shop_cart" action="" method="post">

        <table class="table" class="shop_cart">
          <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Product Preview</th>
                <th>Product Description</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                <th>Price</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>          

          </tbody>
        </table>


    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: are you sure your markup have the empty tbody?

Comment: Create a fiddle demo and reproduce this error. Sure jquery and bootstrap work together easily.

Comment: `$("table tbody").html()`

Comment: looks fine - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/LL1tvmLq/1/ - make sure your script is executed after the table is added to the dom

Comment: Your tbody is empty.

Comment: when i remove class="table" from <table> tag, it works fine.

Comment: I tried in this way too..  $("tbody").empty(); and then $("tbody").html(); i tried making tbody content empty and then tried to get $("tbody").html(); but still getting "undefined"

Answer (score 0):

I got it solved.

Actually * table class="table" class="shop_cart" * has 2 classes mentioned. And the jquery was not processing both in my case. But was processing only first class and ignoring second.

So i made second class to id like this.
 * table class="table" id="shop_cart" *

But still i don't know why it was not processing both. Please let me know if you have any idea. Thanks a lot.

Comment: `<table class="table" class="shop_cart">` is invalid HTML. If you want multiple classes, only use one `class="..."` attribute, like so: `<table class="table shop_cart">` with spaces between each class. Last note, jQuery was only processing the first one because it doesn't know *how* to process a second one, as it's incorrect markup.

Comment: Oh.. thats really cool to mention 2 classes in that way.. Thanks tim. Good information.